# How to create HTML for Multiplication for proper display?

Tags: html

So i started learning html and I've come upon this multiplication html which I saw in image. I even created that but look and feel does not matches the

I was trying to create a HTML.

The horizontal line is not properly displayed and even the digit adjustment is not proper. I have used  proper table and td

[image]

```css
        .old-vertArith-equal-bar {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .old-space-indent {
            margin-left: 32px;
            cursor: default;
        }
```

```html
        <div>
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <div style="text-align:left; position: absolute; left:0">Multiply the ones.</div>
                                    &nbsp;<br><br>
                                    <div class="old-space-indent">
                                        <div style="font-size:125%;">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>3</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">×</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar"></td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">3</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>4</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br><br>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div style="text-align:left; position: absolute; left:0">Multiply the tens.</div>
                                    &nbsp;<br><br>
                                    <div class="old-space-indent">
                                        <div style="font-size:125%;">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>3</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">×</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar"></td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>3</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">2</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>4</td>
                                                                        <td>6</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>9</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>0</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br><br>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div style="text-align:left; position: absolute; left:0">Now add the results.</div>
                                    &nbsp;<br><br>
                                    <div class="old-space-indent">
                                        <div style="font-size:125%;">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>2</td>
                                                                        <td>3</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">×</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar"></td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">3</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">2</td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>4</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="2">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">+</td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>9</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
                                                                            <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>0</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr height="4">
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>7</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>3</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span style="color:green;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br><br>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            The product is 736.
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<table>`'s border to do this instead of `<td>` :

```css
.beautiful-tr {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```css
.old-space-indent {
    margin-left: 32px;
    cursor: default;
}
.beautiful-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div style="text-align:left; position: absolute; left:0">Multiply the ones.</div>
                            &nbsp;<br><br>
                            <div class="old-space-indent">
                                <div style="font-size:125%;">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table class="beautiful-line">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr height="2">
                                                                <td></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>3</b></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr height="2">
                                                                <td></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>×</td>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td>3</td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr height="2">
                                                                <td></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>=</td>
                                                                <td></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span style="color:green;"><b>4</b></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <span style="color:green;"><b>6</b></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br><br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    The product is 736.
</div>
```

PS: I remove few line at the end, to simplify it. Also, you can edit the border thanks to CSS style, with the `beautiful-line` class.

Comment: If you  look 46 is still not at proper place that is causing the main issue

Comment: It's not the line ? Oups sorry, i will edit my answer

Comment: Update: If you add an `=` on first `<td>`, it works fine. So, you have lot of possibilities: keep =, add white char, set min-size to this td...

Comment: in mine for second table its working fine, but again in third table it get distorted a bit

Comment: Now add the result is the last part which also a bit shifted i am taking about this

Comment: Yes, that's why I just edit, and if you add something in the first td it's fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are applying the underline class to each character (which is why there is a small underline only under each character) rather than the whole line of text. To solve this your HTML should go something like this example.:

```
<div class="old-vertArith-equal-bar">
<td>×</td>
<td></td>
<td>3</td>
<td>
<span style="color:#5050ff;"><b>2</b></span>
</td>
</div>
```